# Nested if loop in for loop

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, for-loop, nested

this code just generates a random number to be taken in as the temperature and records it every hour. I am having issues with my for loop on getting the max and min values of my code. It looks correct to me and similar to all the examples I have seen but it's giving me the wrong output.

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void GetValue(int[], int x);
#define array_size 25
int main()  {
    int x, max, min, temperature[25];
    float sum;
    float average;
    int array[array_size];

printf("Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015:\n");
       printf("Time of Day \t Temperature in Degrees F\n");

for (x = 0; x < 25; x++)    {
    //if statements to get min and max
    GetValue(temperature, x);
    if (temperature[x] > max)   {
        max = temperature[x];
    }
    if (temperature[x] < min)   {
        min = temperature[x];
    }
    printf("%d \t \t \t %d\n", x,temperature[x]);
}

//prints statements

printf("\nMaximum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\nMinimum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\n", temperature[12],max, min);

//adds up all temps

sum=0;

for (x=0;x<25;x++){

    sum=(sum+temperature[x]);
}

//prints and creates average

average=sum/25;

printf("Average Temperature for the day: %.2f Degrees F\n",average);

return 0;

}
//gets values and puts them into array

void GetValue(int value[], int x) {

value[x] = (rand()%(100-60+1))+60;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the values of `max` and `min` are at the start of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You invoked *undefine behavior* by using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

- Use values of variables only after assigning some value to them.
- Format your code properly.
- Match format specifier and data for `printf()`.
- Avoid using magic number. Use the `#define`d number for number of elements in this case.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void GetValue(int[], int x);
#define array_size 25
int main(void) {
    int x, max = 0, min = 0, temperature[array_size];
    float sum;
    float average;

    printf("Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015:\n");
    printf("Time of Day \t Temperature in Degrees F\n");

    for (x = 0; x < array_size; x++)    {
        //if statements to get min and max
        GetValue(temperature, x);
        // in the first iteration, there won't be a valid number in max and min
        if (x == 0 || temperature[x] > max)   {
            max = temperature[x];
        }
        if (x == 0 || temperature[x] < min)   {
            min = temperature[x];
        }
        printf("%d \t \t \t %d\n", x, temperature[x]);
    }

    //prints statements

    printf("\nMaximum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\nMinimum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\n", max, min);

    //adds up all temps

    sum=0;

    for (x=0;x<array_size;x++){

        sum=(sum+temperature[x]);
    }

    //prints and creates average

    average=sum/array_size;

    printf("Average Temperature for the day: %.2f Degrees F\n", average);

    return 0;

}
//gets values and puts them into array

void GetValue(int value[], int x) {

    value[x] = (rand()%(100-60+1))+60;
}
```

Comment: @ManishaRamphal I checked [this result](https://ideone.com/cWcP1G) with LibreOffice Calc and I don't think this is wrong. Please give me more detail.

Comment: If a valid temperature is zero and zero is the minimum or maximum, then this code will put the second-lowest or second-highest temperature into `min` or `max`. A better method would be to call `GetValue()` once before the for loop, set both `min` and `max` to this value, run the `for` loop one fewer times, and remove the `== 0` comparisons from the `if`s.

Comment: @JedSchaaf I don't think your formar part of your comment is true. This code returns [correct minimum and maximum value](https://ideone.com/SaREXK) even if `0` is in the dataset and it is minimum. Also why do you think the method in the latter part is better than mine although there will be two expressions that call `GetValue()` while my code have only one?

Comment: @JedSchaaf My code also will work [when the maximum value is 0](https://ideone.com/QL2UOr).

Comment: @MikeCat The temperature i supposed to between 60 and 100 though

Comment: @MikeCAT Sorry, the first part of my comment is wrong. If all the values are positive, then you will not get the correct minimum, but if all the values are negative, then you will not get the correct maximum. My suggestion to fix it will give the right values.

Comment: By starting `min` and `max` at zero, you're artificially adding zero to the values to be considered for the minimum and maximum temperatures. You need to initialize them with the actual values (via `GetValue()` once before the loop) to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @JedSchaaf No, you are wrong. My code [works even if all of the input are negative](https://ideone.com/KVN6wK) and the initialization of `min` and `max` are just for in case there are no input (it won't happen in this code) and it won't mean that 0 is added to the temperature set.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was  wrong. I was reading `x == 0` and thinking `max == 0` at that point, which would have caused the code to always change `max` the next time after any time it became zero (and similarly for `min == 0` instead of `x == 0`). Your code is fine. Have a +1. :)